# reveal.js font-size for li elements

Tags: css, reveal.js

I have the following code in a reveal.js site:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    ol li {
            font-size: 5px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="reveal">
    <div class="slides">
        <section>
            <h3>foo</h3>
            <ol>
                <li value=2>
                    bar
                </li>
                <li value=4>
                    baz
                </li>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the size of the numbers in the ordered list but the css style I added does not accomplish that. Are there reveal.js specific classes i have to overwrite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify the css file of the theme you're using.

The theme file is located in the folder /css/theme/[yourtheme].css

If you open that file you will see a section for the different fonts (the one below is for a header). You would want to look for the css responsible for the particular element of the theme you are interested in changing.

```
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
color: #eee8d5;
font-family: "League Gothic", Impact, sans-serif;
line-height: 0.9em;
letter-spacing: 0.02em;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: none; }
```

Here you can modify the different attributes, including font, of your text.

Hope this helps !
If you have any other questions please ask!